# Environment variable does not seem to work in sudo

Tags: sudo, environment-variables

I use apt behind a firewall, so I specify a proxy in the `http_proxy` environment variable.

What I have done is added the following line to both `.profile` and `.bashrc` (for good measure) of the root user:

```
export http_proxy=http://proxyserver:8080
```

When I do the following, it prints the value of the proxy correctly:

```
sudo echo $http_proxy
```

However, when I call `sudo apt-get update`, it does not seem to see the `http_proxy` variable as the root user.

Only when I su to root, `apt-get` works as expected, through the proxy, so it obviously sees the variable.

So my question is, as above, why does `sudo apt-get` not see the variable?

**UPDATE** I have just learned that when I call `sudo echo`, it echoes the value of the variable set in the current user's profile. But even so, why does `sudo apt-get` not use that variable value?

Comment: Because `sudo` clears any and all environment variables not explicitly whitelisted. Basic security.

Comment: Why then does `sudo echo` work but not `sudo apt-get`?

Comment: @mydoghasworms because `$http_proxy` gets evaluated by the shell and you now run basically `sudo echo http://proxyserver:8080`

Comment: Thanks @UlrichDangel, perhaps you could post this as an answer?

Comment: To properly check the value of http_proxy, you should do `sudo env | grep http_proxy` or `sudo echo '$http_proxy'` instead of `sudo echo $http_proxy`

Answer (score 7):

It doesn't "not seem to work" in the case of `sudo apt-get`, it *seems to work* when you do `sudo echo $http_proxy`.

When you enter a shell command, it globs and expands all variables and aliases *before* it executes.

So `sudo echo $http_proxy` becomes `sudo echo http://proxyserver:8080` which goes through fine.

The reason `$http_proxy` isn't seen by `apt-get` is because `sudo` clears all environment variables except the ones explicitly whitelisted in `/etc/sudoers` with the `env_keep` directive.

More information on how to manipulate the way `sudo` handles environment variables (or rather, how it usually *doesn't*) can be found in `man sudoers`.

Comment: This is the most accurate explanation. To properly check the value of http_proxy, you should do `sudo env | grep http_proxy` or `sudo echo '$http_proxy'` instead of `sudo echo $http_proxy`

Answer (score 4):

Just to let you know, because this is what I settled on, being specific to this case and therefore a better solution, is to modify `/etc/apt/apt.conf` to add a line for the proxy:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://yourproxyaddress:proxyport";
```

As this system resides pretty much permanently behind the proxy, this is a better solution than using the `http_proxy` environment variable in the long run.

Answer (score 3):

Ah, I have just seen something on this page:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto#Setting_up_apt-get_to_use_a_http-proxy

> If you normally use sudo to run apt-get you will need to login as root
> first for this to work unless you also add some explicit environment
> settings to /etc/sudoers, e.g.
>
> `Defaults env_keep = "http_proxy https_proxy ftp_proxy"`

The reason you need to do is is because `sudo` deliberately clears any and all environment variables *nod* so whitelisted as a basic security precaution.

Comment: Hello Shadur, I have rolled back your edit. Can I ask that you please add what you said after the last paragraph, as what I said is still valid for me and I would first want to hear your explanation to my comment above. Thanks.

Comment: On second thought, Shadur, I believe your addition actually belongs in its own answer.

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out, `sudo` clears custom environment variables set by the user.

As a workaround you could try:

```
export http_proxy='http://proxyserver:8080'
sudo sh -c 'export "${1}"; echo "$http_proxy"; apt-get update' _ "http_proxy=${http_proxy}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you just need to use the '-E' option for sudo, e.g.

```
sudo -E echo $http_proxy
```

Comment: No, the http_proxy variable gets extended before the sudo run, and the shell then runs `sudo -E echo ADDRESS_OF_PROXY`